# jniopencv_objdetect.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, javacv, face-recognition

First sorry for my bad english..

Well, i'm having a huge problem with the 2 .jar or libraries JAVACV and OPENCV, i'm triying to build a LOGIN with Face tracking and Face Recognition, but when i try to run the Main.java popups this problem:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_objdetect in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:701)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:578)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.<clinit>(opencv_objdetect.java:91)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:553)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect$CvHaarClassifierCascade.<clinit>(opencv_objdetect.java:170)
    at reconocimiento.ReconocimientoCaras.<init>(ReconocimientoCaras.java:51)
    at reconocimiento.ReconocimientoCaras.<clinit>(ReconocimientoCaras.java:53)
    at reconocimiento.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp42613800564148\jniopencv_objdetect.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:690)
    ... 11 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your OS that whether it is 32bit or 64bit.Then install the appropriate version opencv and javacv.

Comment: Thanks, like 3 weeks ago i realize that my OS don't have some libraries in system32 that windows 32 bit have, i'm gonna code this in 32 bit OS, thanks!